# laravel displaying path which matches business_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am allowing business to upload images. Everything is saved into database and the only thing I need to do is retrieve  images that match business_id:

[image]

So now I need to browse throught business_id and if it's matching, output all images.

```
function displayBusiness($id) {
    $business = Business::find($id);
    $address = Address::find($id);
    $session = session()->put('key', $id);
    $session = session()->get('key');
    $retrieve_gallery = Gallery::where('business_id', '=' ,$session)->firstOrFail();
    return view('displayBusiness', compact('business', 'address', 'gallery'));
}
```

In session variable I am storing a business id from business table. I want to match that session variable with each business_id in database and return compact 'gallery' so I can use it's path in view:

```
<img class="images" src="{{ asset($gallery->path) }}" />
```

However I get $gallery is not defined. How can that be fixed?

Comment: what do you expect, gallery isn't defined anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get()` to get a collection of images:

```
$gallery = Gallery::where('business_id', $id)->get();
```

Then iterate over images to display them:

```
@foreach ($gallery as $image)
    <img class="images" src="{{ asset($image->path) }}" />
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't create a $gallery variable before you call it on compact().

So when you do

```
compact('business', 'address', 'gallery')
```

It's like doing

```
['business' => $business, 'address' => $address];
```

Note that compact() will not issue a warning if a value is undefined (see the docs for compact function, first user contribution note :http://php.net/manual/fr/function.compact.php#101775).

As a result, $gallery is indeed undefined in your exemple.

So changing **$retrieve_gallery** to **$gallery** should solve that particular problem you mention.